# get by id in hibernate returns null when id is defined in the parent entity

Tags: java, hibernate, single-table-inheritance

I have 3 entities, all mapped to the same base table, like this:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
   discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING,
   name = "disc_type"
)
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "unique_id", nullable = false)
    private long id;
}

@DiscriminatorValue(value = DiscType.Values.ONE)
public class Child1 extends Parent {
}

@DiscriminatorValue(value = DiscType.Values.TWO)
public class Child2 extends Parent {
}
```

What doesn't work for me is when I try get by id for the child entities - I would have expected the following code to work (and adding the matching disc_type filter), but unfortunately - this returns null:

```
return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Child1.class, id);
```

While this returns (as expected) the Parent object:

```
return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Parent.class, id);
```

I need to return a Child1 entity, and converting the Parent to Child1 seems like a pretty bad solution. Ideas on how to get over this?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried following code and it works (hope this helps):

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
   discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING,
   name = "disc_type"
)
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@Data
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "unique_id", nullable = false)
    private long id;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "ONE")
public class Child1 extends Parent {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "TWO")
public class Child2 extends Parent {
}

public interface EntityRepository extends CrudRepository<Parent, Long> {
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class ApplicationRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
        private final EntityRepository repository;

        @Override
        public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
            repository.save(new Child1());
            repository.save(new Child2());
            Parent one = repository.findById(1L).get();
            System.out.println(one);
            Parent two = repository.findById(2L).get();
            System.out.println(two);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hibernate: insert into parent (unique_id, disc_type) values (null, 'ONE')
Hibernate: insert into parent (unique_id, disc_type) values (null, 'TWO')
Hibernate: select parent0_.unique_id as unique_i2_2_0_, parent0_.disc_type as disc_typ1_2_0_ from parent parent0_ where parent0_.unique_id=?
Parent(id=1)
Hibernate: select parent0_.unique_id as unique_i2_2_0_, parent0_.disc_type as disc_typ1_2_0_ from parent parent0_ where parent0_.unique_id=?
Parent(id=2)
```

**Update:**

```
public interface Child1Repository extends CrudRepository<Child1, Long> {
}

@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final EntityRepository repository;
    private final Child1Repository child1Repository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        repository.save(new Child1());
        repository.save(new Child2());
        Parent one = repository.findById(1L).get();
        System.out.println(one);
        Parent two = repository.findById(2L).get();
        System.out.println(two);
        Child1 child1 = child1Repository.findById(1L).get();
        System.out.println(child1);
    }
}
```

Comment: not really solving my problem unfortunately - I need to get a Child1 object, not a Parent object. Again, I can convert obviously, it just seems weird to me that Hibernate wouldn't allow me perform a get directly on the Child1 entity.

Comment: You can add repository dedicated to Child1 (look at my update section of the answer)

Comment: Thanks, looks good. Will mark as answered once I'll implement:)